# how to compare anchor ID attribute to other id Jquery?

Tags: jquery, anchor

I want to compare anchor Id attribute to that given ID which i get it before from that same anchor tag and after comparing i want to **remove** the closest **tr tag**. That's tr has been create dynamically.I have to tried the following code. But it's not working correctly .
Any help regarding this issue will be appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<td>
  <div class='form-group'>
    <a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='RemoveThisItem(tId)' title='Remove'><i class='fa fa-fw fa-trash-o'></i></a>
  </div>
</td>
```

remove following tr as well

```
<tr class='showRadioRow' style='display:none;'>
    <td colspan='2'>
      <div class='form-group'>
        <label for=''><b>Number of Radio Option:</b></label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control getRadioValue' name='test'/>
      </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**JQUERY**

```
function RemoveThisItem(val){
    var id=$('#'+val);
    $(id).remove();
    $('a').attr('id').eq(id).closest('tr.showRadioRow').remove();   
}
```

**SNIPPET**
http://jsfiddle.net/jaykhan47/k471gh5h/4/

Comment: Where have you defined the variable `tId`, and what is its value?

Comment: Probably easier to use DOM traversal instead of a convoluted `id` lookup pattern. Could you edit the question to include a more complete sample of your table's HTML after some rows have been loaded. Also note that you should avoid `on*` event attributes. Use delegated event handlers.

Comment: Add a working snippet with your problem. Not bits and chunks of code

Comment: you remove the anchor element with `$(id).remove();` and then on the following line you try and match it to something. But it no longer exists so it can't find it. Also "closest" removes the closest parent element matching the selector. But it look like in this case showRadioRow is not an ancestor of your anchor tag?

Comment: The anchor tag also created dynamically and assign ID by `var tId=$.now(); ` .

Comment: Also from your snippet it's not clear which element is actually supposed to have the ID which matches tID? None of the elements shown actually have an ID attribute of any sort.

Comment: Check the snippet:   http://jsfiddle.net/jaykhan47/k471gh5h/

Comment: `.eq` will match by index - `.eq(index)` https://api.jquery.com/eq/ - you're using it as `.eq($('#'+val))` which makes no sense.

Comment: Check the console for errors in your fiddle - you hadn't included jquery, but with jquery added, it still gives errors.  http://jsfiddle.net/k471gh5h/2/

Answer (score 2):

Resolve the problem:

```
function RemoveThisItem(val){
    var id=$('#'+val);
     //console.log(id);
    //console.log(id[0].nextSibling);
    var tr=id[0].nextSibling;
    tr.remove();
    $(id).remove();     
}
```